# How to use sharePreference in Asynctask

Tags: android

I am doing login, after user managed to login *I want all the user information store in `SharedPreference`*. **I am not able to retrieve the user information** and I am just able to login. I am new to android. I have read a lot regarding `SharedPref`. but do not know how to apply in my code. This is my code:

```
    public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
        Context context;
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        public BackgroundWorker(Context ctx) {
            context = ctx;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String type = params[0];
            String login_url = "http://eateathere.com/login.php";
            String register_url = "http://eateathere.com/signup.php";
            String navigate = "http://eateathere.com/res_retrieve.php";

            if (type.equals("login")) {
                try {
                    String user_name = params[1];
                    String password = params[2];
                    URL url = new URL(login_url);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                    String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                            +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                    bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                    String result ="";
                    String line;
                    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                        result += line;
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return result;
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }   
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute () {
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Status");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (String result){
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
            // Intent in = new Intent(context, Homepage.class);
            //context.startActivity(in);
            if(result == null)
            {
                // do what you want to do
            }
            else if (result.contains("Login Success"))  // msg you get from success like "Login Success"
            {
//I have problem here
                 String name = params[1];
                 String pass = params[2];
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
                edit.putString("user_name", name);
                edit.commit();
                SharedPreferences sp2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit2 = sp2.edit();
                edit2.putString("password", pass);
                edit2.commit();
                Intent in = new Intent(context, Homepage.class);
                context.startActivity(in);
                alertDialog.setMessage(result);
                alertDialog.show();
            }
```

Appreciate if someone can tell me on how to use SharedPreferences so that I can continue my project.

Comment: Have you gone through it : https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial

Comment: Does this compile? `getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);`? Your current class is not MainActivity. Also, you only need one instance of the preferences, not one per value to edit

Comment: `params` is a local variable to `doInBackground` , keep a reference to it inside class

Comment: You need to move the username and password to either the constructor or as fields